# Accessing to all the elements from the single member type from the struct in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Lets say I have a following structures in c++

```
struct Fruit
  {
     std::string name, description;
  }
```

and

```
struct Fruit Fruits[]
  {
    {"orange"," Orange is a hybrid of ancient cultivated origin, possibly between pomelo and mandarin. "},
    {"apple", " Apple is the pomaceous fruit of the apple tree, species Malus domestica in the rose family. "},
  };
```

My question is, how can I access to all the elements of the single member type of the one struct in c++, or in this case how can I list all the elements of the member type name from the struct Fruit?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That isn't real code. At all.

Comment: What other settings and suggestions would you introduce for this issue, @KerrekSB?

Comment: I think Kerrek is pointing out that your "Fruits" struct isn't really a struct. You are trying to represent a collection of fruits where the first is initialized as orange, and the second is initialized as apple. Your fruits would really be an array of Fruit, or a std::vector of Fruit, or a std::map of Fruit, etc. Where in that array/vector/map you start adding actual instances of a fruit -- similar to Kerrek's example below.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add [] for the 
`struct Fruit Fruits[]`

Comment: I was thinking to store them in a struct using two member types name and description, in which later on I will call that struct to form my way of lets say stacked fruits instances, by calling a Fruit struct in another struct, Fruits. So, each element of the struct Fruits holds two member types of the Fruit struct. My question was, can I somehow retrieve all the elements of the one membertype using this way of building an array or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I list all the elements of the member type `name` from the `struct Fruit`?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Fruit
  {
     std::string name, description;
  };

struct Fruit Fruits[] =
  {
    {"orange"," Orange is a hybrid of ancient cultivated origin, possibly between pomelo and mandarin. "},
    {"apple", " Apple is the pomaceous fruit of the apple tree, species Malus domestica in the rose family. "},
  };

int main () {
  for(auto& fruit : Fruits ) {
    std::cout << fruit.name << "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was searching for! :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need a dynamic array of pears:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> fruits {
   { "Apple", "Yum" },
   { "Tomato", "Yuck" }
};
```

You can iterate this:

```
for (auto it = fruits.cbegin(), end = fruits.cend(); it != end; ++it)
{
    std::cout << "Fruit: " << it->first << ", Description: " << it->second << "\n";
}
```

Or use the snazzy new range-for-loop:

```
for (auto const & p : fruits) { /* ... p.first etc ... */ }
```

Comment: It's an interesting proposal, but is it possible that I somehow access to all the elements of the member type in the way I posted.